# How to include class in link_to remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this code and I want to include glyphicon, but the code below is not working. If I remove the class `subcomment_link`, it will work, but I really need to include it for `jquery`. What is the correct syntax for `link_to` with remote with class specified?

```
<%= link_to new_subcomment_path(:response_id => response.id), class: "subcomment_link", id: "reply_new_subcomment#{response.id}", remote: true do %> 
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>&nbsp Edit your profile 
<% end %>
```

Comment: `The code below is not working` - more details, please? Do you get an exception, if not how does rendered html look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
<%= link_to new_subcomment_path(:response_id => response.id), {remote: true}, {class: "subcomment_link", id: "reply_new_subcomment#{response.id}"} do %>
```

Usually the tag options come before the html options.